# Automatically scrolls page up javascript slider (myself created)

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I created javascript slider, which automatically pulls page up, when it goes to next tab. You can test it in your page, and you will see, how to fix that? It pulls page up, like there would be href="#top" and  , but there isn't anything like that.

Code -

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            var time = <?php echo $data['tab1_speed']; ?>;          
            var tripleboxTitle = jQuery("triplebox-tab-title");
            setInterval(function() {
                tripleboxTitle.click(function(){
                    clearInterval();
                });
                var currentTab = jQuery('.triplebox-tab-active').attr("tab");
                var newTab = Number(currentTab)+1;
                if(newTab > 3) {
                    newTab = 1;
                }
                console.log(newTab);
                jQuery(".triplebox-tab-title").removeClass('triplebox-tab-active');
                jQuery('#triplebox-widget-tab'+newTab).addClass('triplebox-tab-active');
                jQuery(".triplebox-tab-default").hide();
                jQuery(".triplebox-tab-default").removeClass('triplebox-tab-default');
                jQuery("#triplebox-widget-tab"+newTab+"-widget").addClass('triplebox-tab-default').fadeIn(300);
            }, time);
        });
    </script>
    <a id="triplebox-widget-tab1" tab="1" class="triplebox-tab-title triplebox-tab-active" <?php if($data['use_color'] == 'default') { ?>style="color: <?php echo $data['color_text']; ?>; background: <?php echo $data['color_tabs']; ?>;" <?php } ?>><?php echo $data['tab1_name']; ?></a>
    <a id="triplebox-widget-tab2" tab="2" class="triplebox-tab-title" <?php if($data['use_color'] == 'default') { ?>style="color: <?php echo $data['color_text']; ?>; background: <?php echo $data['color_tabs']; ?>;" <?php } ?>><?php echo $data['tab2_name']; ?></a>
    <a id="triplebox-widget-tab3" tab="3" class="triplebox-tab-title" <?php if($data['use_color'] == 'default') { ?>style="color: <?php echo $data['color_text']; ?>; background: <?php echo $data['color_tabs']; ?>;" <?php } ?>><?php echo $data['tab3_name']; ?></a>

    <div id="triplebox-widget-tab1-widget" class="triplebox-widget triplebox-tab-default" <?php if($data['use_color'] == 'default') { ?>style="background: <?php echo $data['color_content']; ?>; color: <?php echo $data['color_text']; ?>;"<?php } ?>>
        <?php echo $content; ?>
    </div>
    <div id="triplebox-widget-tab2-widget" class="triplebox-widget" style=" <?php if($data['use_color'] == 'default') { ?>background: <?php echo $data['color_content']; ?>; color: <?php echo $data['color_text']; ?>;<?php } ?> display: none;">
        <?php echo $content2; ?>
    </div>
    <div id="triplebox-widget-tab3-widget" class="triplebox-widget" style=" <?php if($data['use_color'] == 'default') { ?>background: <?php echo $data['color_content']; ?>; color: <?php echo $data['color_text']; ?>;<?php } ?> display: none;">
        <?php echo $content3; ?>
    </div>
```

Also, why is my clearInterval(); not working? It still continues to scroll. How to make it stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass to function an "intervalID"

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval#Example

So;

```
var tripleboxTitle = jQuery("triplebox-tab-title");
var myIntvID = setInterval(function() {
...
tripleboxTitle.click(function(){
   clearInterval(myIntvID);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, somehow missed that ;)!